# When does a flurry of blows occur when attacking multiple enemies at once?

Tags: dnd-4e, monk

I have a question concerning the monk class in the PHB3:

On this page I have read the following conerning five storms:
http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2416336

> Be aware that when you use this you likely won't get to use your extra rider effect from flurry of blows, the extra damage from Stone Fist or the any direction slide from Centered Breath because you targeted all adjacent targets.

I haven't read anywhere in PHB3 that attacking several enemies doesn't allow the use of the flurry feature. Does the "likely" refer to another book?

If I can use the flurry, do I understand it properly that I can use the flurry right after the hit of at least one enemy is determined or do I need to wait until the attack is resolved?

E.g. Five Storms: Do I use the flurry power at the end of the attack or can I as well use it after I rolled and hit the first enemy and e.g. slide another enemy into burst 1?

Comment: You seem to be talking about D&D 4e, so I've retagged your question with its tag. Please tag your question with the specific version you're playing next time. And welcome to the site!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text you quote never states about the possibility of using Flurry of Blows like you seem to believe.

Instead, it tells you that you won't be able to apply the rider, that is the additional effect, since it is only triggered if you hit a different target than the one you hit with your main attack. Having targeted all the enemies you can reach with a Flurry with your attack power, you can't choose a different one. You will then deal the Flurry of Blows damage, but no *rider*.

Comment: Ok, you don't get the additional damage for those you attacked:
"If the target wasn't targeted by the triggering attack, the damage increases by 2."

Comment: @Telandor that depends on the specific rider of the Flurry of your monastic school, but you got the gist of it.

Comment: @telandor that's definitely a different question and you should ask it separately. Questions are free ;) (and comments can get deleted)